# How to recover dpkg from corrupted downloads?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I just upgraded to the 10.10 RC earlier and had a few problems with graphic drivers (x didnt start) But i have remedied that now.
When i run 'sudo apt-get install -f' i get this:

```
will@UbuntuBox:/mnt/slax$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for will: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmono-wcf3.0-cil openoffice.org-calc openoffice.org-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmono-wcf3.0-cil
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openoffice.org-calc openoffice.org-core
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
16 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/32.5MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,929kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 201565 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace openoffice.org-calc 1:3.2.1-6ubuntu2~10.04.1 (using .../openoffice.org-calc_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement openoffice.org-calc ...
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openoffice.org-calc_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./usr/lib/openoffice/basis3.2/program/libscfiltli.so'
dpkg: regarding .../openoffice.org-core_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb containing openoffice.org-core:
 openoffice.org-core conflicts with openoffice.org-calc (<< 1:3.2.1-7ubuntu1)
  openoffice.org-calc (version 1:3.2.1-6ubuntu2~10.04.1) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openoffice.org-core_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing openoffice.org-core
Unpacking libmono-wcf3.0-cil (from .../libmono-wcf3.0-cil_2.6.7-3ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:0>: data error'
dpkg-deb: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmono-wcf3.0-cil_2.6.7-3ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openoffice.org-calc_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openoffice.org-core_1%3a3.2.1-7ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmono-wcf3.0-cil_2.6.7-3ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how i can get the broken packages fixed?
Cheers,
Will

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This line is a clue:

```
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
```

Perhaps something happened to the .deb during transfer. Execute a `sudo apt-get clean` and then try again to force it to redownload the debs.

There are [similar reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/652408) in Launchpad on these kind of errors for OpenOffice lately. This is likely a bug and [should be reported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) as such.

Comment: I was facing this issue when I upgraded to ubuntu 20